# Create a "do-nothing" `std::function` with any signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates, std-function

I would like to create a simple no-op `std::function` object with an arbitrary signature. To that end, I've created two functions:

```
template <typename RESULT, typename... ArgsProto>
  std::function<RESULT(ArgsProto...)> GetFuncNoOp()
  {
    // The "default-initialize-and-return" lambda
    return [](ArgsProto...)->RESULT { return {}; };
  }

template <typename... ArgsProto>
  std::function<void(ArgsProto...)> GetFuncNoOp()
  {
    // The "do-nothing" lambda
    return [](ArgsProto...)->void {};
  }
```

Each of these works well enough (obviously the first version might create uninitialized data members in the `RESULT` object, but in practice I don't think that would be much of a problem). But the second, `void`-returning version is necessary because `return {};` *never* returns `void` (this would be a compile error), and it can't be written as a template-specialization of the first because the initial signature is variadic.

So I am forced to either pick between these two functions and only implement one, or give them different names. But all I *really* want is to easily initialize `std::function` objects in such a way that, when called, they do nothing rather than throwing an exception. Is this possible?

Note that [the default constructor of `std::function` does not do what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526853/1858225).

Comment: `std::function< std::string const&() >` is an example where the technique fails (and really, can not not fail).

Comment: @Yakk Right, because it's impossible (of course) for a "no-op" func to return a reference, because what could it possibly return a reference to?

Comment: `static T; return T;` ;)

Comment: @Yakk Oh, right, of course. Can that be applied to your solution by returning something like `static anything instance{}`?

Comment: Oops, forgot that it's the `anything::()` that must return a reference, rather than `noop::()`.

Comment: @Yakk: That does assume `T::T()` exists and is accessible. `throw std::logic_error(); return *(T*)nullptr;` comes to mind.

Comment: @MSalters rather, `=delete` to catch the error at compile time.  A function that always throws seems like a bad function to store somewhere!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like having to specify the signature.

Assuming you have a `std::function` implementation where `std::function<void()>` can accept a function pointer of type `int(*)()`, this is a non-type erased `noop` object that can be cast into any `std::function`:

```
struct noop {
  struct anything {
    template<class T>
    operator T(){ return {}; }
    // optional reference support.  Somewhat evil.
    template<class T>
    operator T&()const{ static T t{}; return t; }
  };
  template<class...Args>
  anything operator()(Args&&...)const{return {};}
};
```

if your `std::function` does not support that conversion, we add:

```
  template<class...Args>
  operator std::function<void(Args...)>() {
    return [](auto&&...){};
  }
```

which should handle that case, assuming your `std::function` is SFINAE friendly.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c432523d47788a3e).

To use, just use `noop{}`.  If you really need a function returning a noop, do `inline noop GetFuncNoop(){ return{}; }`.

A side benefit to this is that if you pass the `noop` to a non-type erasing operation, we don't get pointless `std::function` overhead for doing nothing.

The reference support is evil because it creates a global object and propogates references to it all over the place.  If one `std::function<std::string&()>` is called, and the resulting `string` modified, the modified string is used everywhere (and without any synchronization between uses).  Plus allocating global resources without telling anyone seems rude.

I'd just `=delete` the `operator T&` case instead, and generate a compile-time error.

Comment: Huh. Specifying the signature is indeed a pretty bad annoyance with T.C.'s correction of my solution, so I do like this better, but I don't quite understand it. Why does `anything::()<void> {return {}; }` (i.e. the specialization of `anything::()` to `void`) not cause a compile error, since `return {};` can't be used to return `void`?

Comment: Also, would you mind putting the `reference-returning` version back in your answer, with a brief explanation of why you think it's "evil" (or dangerous or whatever)?

Comment: @KyleStrand `std::function<void()>` never tries to convert the return value of the passed in object to `void` in modern implementations.  So the returned `anything` is just discarded.  Some of the evil of the reference-returning `anything` is now added, and I made it work (original version didn't work, required some finessing of `const` to make it work right).  `noop` **always** returns an `anything`.  The `anything` can be converted to anything, which is what lets it match any `std::function` signature's return value requirements.

Comment: Awesome. I'm changing `operator T&()` to return `T const&` (and changing `static T t` to `static const T t`), which provides *some* safety, and for a do-nothing function, that's probably good enough.

Comment: ....how is the `anything::()` overload even disambiguated, though? `noop::()` never returns a `const`, yet everything appears to work as expected (though I expect the actual print operation is undefined behavior): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5831256cb7e60d22

Comment: @KyleStrand First, make the `operator T()` non-const. That makes it preferred, which disambiguates in the `int x = noop::anything{};` case.  Second, `int const& y = noop::anything{};` prefers the `operator T const&()const`  over `operator T()` despite the failure for the type of `this` to match, at least in practice. (by working directly with `noop::anything{}` you get much better error messages). I'd have to do some work to find standard quotes proving that this is correct. There is no undefined behavior as far as I can tell, all the references are grounded in function-local `static` objects.

Comment: `static const T t;` can be undefined depending on the type of `T`; if `T` has no user-defined initializer, I don't think Clang will even compile that code: http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#default_init_const (I've changed this to `static const T t{}`, which ensures some kind of initialization.)

Comment: Indeed, leaving off the `{}` causes an error on clang when using a POD class as a return type. But there's another error with Clang++ that I don't quite understand, when trying to instantiate a `noop` that takes a `std::string` as an argument: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82639/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-yakk).

Answer (score 11):

You are too wedded to braces.

```
template <typename RESULT, typename... ArgsProto>
std::function<RESULT(ArgsProto...)> GetFuncNoOp()
{
  // && avoids unnecessary copying. Thanks @Yakk
  return [](ArgsProto&&...) { return RESULT(); }; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that `void()` could be "initialized" in that way. What's actually going on there? Is it any different from `return;` ?

Comment: @KyleStrand Nothing different. `void()` is a prvalue of type `void`, that's all.

Comment: ....and I notice that `RESULT{}` does not behave the same. Yet another issue with "univeral" initialization syntax?

Comment: @KyleStrand Yes. `void()` is fine; `void{}` isn't. No idea why they made it that way.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class T> struct dummy {
  static auto get() -> T { return {}; }
};
template <> struct dummy<void> {
  static auto get() -> void {}
};

template <typename RESULT, typename... ArgsProto>
std::function<RESULT(ArgsProto...)> GetFuncNoOp()
{
  return [](ArgsProto...)->RESULT { return dummy<RESULT>::get(); };
}
```

but... @T.C. solution is so much more elegant. Just wanted to show another way that can be applied anywhere you need to specialize just a "part" of something.