# How to construct no-op callback from std::function signature in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, callback

I have some callback definition like:

```
using TSomeCallback = std::function<ReturnType(Type1, Type2, Type3, …)>;
```

Also I have some method that accepts this callback as an argument:

```
void SetCallback(TSomeCallback);
```

All I want is to define some template that instantiates no-op callback **directly from TSomeCallback**:

```
void SetCallback(TSomeCallback = GetNoopCallback<TSomeCallback>());  // or
void SetCallback(TSomeCallback = GetNoopCallback(TSomeCallback()));  // or any other way.
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31274968/377393) answer - it's good, but I don't know how to improve it for my purpose.

Comment: whats the problem with the answer you found? `TSomeCallback t = GetFuncNoOp<void,Type1, Type2, Type3, …>();`  should do the job

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way

```
void SetCallback(TSomeCallback = [](auto...){});
```

but I would recommend rather

```
void SetCallback(TSomeCallback = {})
```

and check for the callback being non-empty inside. Or perhaps don't supply a default parameter and just don't call `SetCallback` if you don't want to be called back!

Comment: even with the default the `std::function` might be empty, hence `{}` is the best suggestion imho. ( fwiw: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number An empty std::function is different from a "noop" std::function (An empty std::function is like `[](auto&&...) { throw std::bad_function_call{}; }`)

Comment: @Artyer yes. Maybe the comment was not clear. Without the default: `void SetCallback(TSomeCallback)` can be called with an empty / default constructed `std::function`. The noop OP is asking for is false security ("its always a valid function" but it isnt really). Hence I think the best is to use `{}` as default and check for emptyness (because the check for emptyness should be there anyhow)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda to construct a `std::function< ... >` that does nothing. Provided, the return type is `void` then this works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
     
using TSomeCallback = std::function<void(int,double,int)>;
     
int main() {
    TSomeCallback tc = [](auto...){};
    tc(42,12.0,42);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `GetNoopCallback` for `void`-returning functions like this:

```
template <class F>
F GetNoopCallback() {
    return [](auto&&...){};
}
```

Then:

```
void SetCallback(TSomeCallback = GetNoopCallback<TSomeCallback>());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename result>
requires (std::is_void_v<result> ||
          std::is_default_costructible_v<result>)
constexpr auto return_default = [] (auto&& ...)
noexcept (std::is_void_v<result> ||
          std::is_nothrow_default_costructible_v<result>)
{
    if  constexpr (std::is_void_v<result>)
        return;
    else
        return result {};
};
```

Now just cast or use the template variable as rvalue:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = return_default<void>;
auto f2 = std::function<A(B,C)>{return_default<A>};
```

You can take one step further to remove the need for a return type:

```
struct any_function_default{
    template<typename result, typname ... args>
    requires (std::is_void_v<result> ||
              std::is_default_costructible_v<result>)
    constexpr operator std::function<result(args ...)> () const {
        return [] (auto&& ...) {
               if  constexpr (std::is_void_v<result>)
                   return;
               else
                   return result {};
        };
    };
};
```

Now use `any_function_default` as the universal default for functions:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = any_function_default{};
auto f2 = std::function<A(B,C)> { any_function_default{} };
```